# Get URL response code and store it in variable using https.get

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm simply using `https.get` to retrieve a URL response code, but I don't want to just show it in the console, I want to store it in array to later insert it in a DB table. Here's what I'm doing:

```
results.forEach((element, index) => {
 link[index] = element.AppURLAndroid;
 https.get(link[index], function(res) {
   resCode[index] = res.statusCode;
  }).on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
  });                
});
```

As you can see, I'm retrieving the URLs from an array, getting the response code, and trying to store it in another array. The problem relies in this line `resCode[index] = res.statusCode;` .. if I do `console.log` it works fine and I can see the response code, but somehow I just can't assign it into a variable or array. I also tried using a global variable like `global.resCodeTemp`, but it also doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

[EDIT] : there are no error thrown, I just try to print the array after the insertion and the array is empty.

Comment: Describe properly why you can't assign to variable.
Is it throwing error or not stored properly?

Comment: No it doesn't throw any errors, nothing happens, I just try to print the array and it's empty. If there were any errors or more detailed I would've put them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try below code. In below code I have pass index in function to use in rescode.

```
results.forEach((element, index) => {
 link[index] = element.AppURLAndroid;
 https.get(link[index], function(res,index) {
   resCode[index] = res.statusCode;
  }).on('error', function(e) {
  console.error(e);
  });                
});
```